# Fedora 23 Server 64-bit install fails to complete on virtual machine in Windows 10

Tags: fedora, windows, virtual-machine, webserver, file-server

While attempting to install Fedora SERVER from an iso:

```
Fedora-Server-netinst-x86_64-23.iso
```

the installation stalls completely on `Creating ext4 on /dev/sda1`. I am using VMware Workstation 12 Player running on the latest version of Windows 10 with all available updates installed. Fedora has been assigned the default 20GB partition and 1GB of RAM at present.

Terminal output shows as follows:

[image: Console output]

Attempting to run `ls` command from any directory in root@localhost results in a

`Segmentation fault`

However, navigating to the `/tmp` directory does seem to work, so I know the directory is there...

Log contents:

[image: Logs]

Comment: Does anything from Fedora's [How to debug installation problems](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_debug_installation_problems) page help? In particular, take a look at the terminal on `ctrl-alt-f4`. And, what do the logs in `/tmp` show?

Comment: Added terminal output to question.

Comment: `ctrl-alt-f2` should give you a shell to look at the logs. The various errors about "Read-only filesystem" jump out at me. Is that also in the logs earlier?

Comment: added log contents

Comment: For `netinst` you need to have internet set up somehow in the WMthing.

Comment: The internet shows as being connected on the VM screen doodar in the top right...

Comment: Also, why was the Fedora console showing 'wired' as the connection when I was connected wirelessly?